# OpenErp 6.0 Payroll

Tags: odoo

**OpenERP** how to calculate  Tax on  **based on text box** in **HR**-> Configuration->payroll -> salary heads there is text box “**Based on**” I want to put income tax calculation on basic

if basic < 150

```
 don’t deduct
```

else if basic < 650

```
  deduct basic*0.1 -50
```

elseif basic <1400

```
  deduct basic*0.15 -270
```

I need to calculate something like this can you Please help me I’m from Ethiopia your help is very much appreciated. 
I’m using OpenERP 6.0 v

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using OpenERP 6.1 - you might wish to upgrade as it has much better interface imho.

In 6.1, you will add a Salary rule to a Salary structure, which is bound to an employee's contract.

The Salary rule will hold the calculation. In essence, you have two options there:

1) write all calculation in the python code of a single rule - something like this:

```
if categories.BASIC < 150:
    result = 0
elif categories.BASIC < 650:
    result = - categories.BASIC * 0.1 + 50
else:
    result = - categories.BASIC * 0.15 + 270
```

2) use a range condition of the rule based on categories.BASIC and define a few rules with python still:

```
# For 150 - 650
result = - categories.BASIC * 0.1 + 50

# For 650 - 1400
result = - categories.BASIC * 0.15 + 270
```

3) If you want to complicate it further, go for a range-condition percentage-value rules, then you don't need to put any python code in the rules, but you'll have double the number of rules - one set for percentage (-basic*0.1) and one set for the offset (50)

Depends what you prefer as this will decide how the payslip will look like. Though the financial effect will be the same.

Forgot to mention, that the Sequence number is essential! the categories.BASIC will only include values of rules which have been calculated earlier according to the sequence number.